# Explain use of could in this line

Tags: lyrics

Please explain this line - taken from song History by One Direction.

> We could be the greatest Team that the world has ever seen.

Does it refer to past? They could be the greatest team ? Or does it means they can be the greatest team in future?

Comment: Are they talking about themselves?  In addition to its other meanings "could" refers to a hypothetical situation either in the future or even at present.

Comment: Consider [waiting longer](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer) before accepting an answer. You might receive more or better answers that way.

Comment: Yeah! But your answer was comprehensive,explanatory. and it cleared up all of my doubts. that's why I accepted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the snippet you have provided is not enough to determine the intended meaning. In this case, it can be a present or future possibility.

From the Cambridge Dictionary,

> [*Could*: uses](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/could)
>   Possibility
>
> We often use could to express possibility in the present and the future.

If you read (or listen) to the lyrics, then it sounds like the singer and a partner are breaking up. The singer then says

> You and me got a whole lot of history (oh)
>   We could be the greatest team that the world has ever seen
>   You and me got a whole lot of history (oh)
>   So don't let it go, we can make some more, we can live forever
>   ([Source.](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/onedirection/history.html))

Taking all of this into consideration, we can determine that the singer is suggesting that "they can be the greatest team in future".